Create kotlin class at runtime using kotlin scripting which inherits another class
I want to create a class at runtime
fun generateQueryableClassFromAttributes(
        attributes: Map<String, KClass<*>>,
        className: String,
    ){
        val classSource = buildString {

            append("class $className (val id: String) : Queryable() {\n")
            for ((key, value) in attributes) {
                append("    var `$key`: ${value.qualifiedName}? = null\n")
            }
            append("}")
        }
     
        val compilationConfiguration = ScriptCompilationConfiguration {
            jvm {
                dependenciesFromClassContext(ImportQueryable::class, wholeClasspath = true)
                baseClass(Queryable::class)
                defaultImports(
                    "com.myclass.Queryable",
                    "java.util.UUID",
                )
            }
        }
        val scriptSource = classSource.toScriptSource(className)

        // Evaluate the script
        val result = BasicJvmScriptingHost().eval(scriptSource, compilationConfiguration, ScriptEvaluationConfiguration())
        val scriptInstance = result.valueOrThrow().returnValue.scriptInstance
        val scriptClass = scriptInstance.javaClass.kotlin
        println(scriptClass.constructors)       
    }

I get [fun (): Name] as the output of the constructor. I am not able to get the constructor which I have specified which takes a string parameter. scriptClass.members also returns only the inherited members and not the properties that have been added
How should I go about adding the constructor so that I can see it ?
Also how can I set a property ex:
val queryableInstance = queryableClass.primaryConstructor!!.call()
queryableInstance.set("name","Random") where `name` is present in `attributes`

